# PHP How to delete post in group?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I want to delete post in facebook group with method:

**https://graph.facebook.com/**{Post-ID}/**?method=delete&access_token=**{Admin token}

And it displayed: (#200) Permissions error

[image]

But I can delete comments in post with comment-id

How to fix? Please!!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/group/feed
,you cant.

> Deleting
>   This operation is not supported.